# What causes certain jivas to be hot-headed?

Tags: krodha, rajas

Other than unfulfilled desires that give rise to rage and anger (as mentioned in the Gita), what are some other factors that causes certain people to be hot-headed?

It would be helpful to know whether gunas such as rajas is also responsible for our anger issues.

It is understandable that wordly people, due to their unfulfilled desires or family tensions, are quick to anger, but why did sages in the past, such as Durvasa, who probably conquered the vices of maya, often cursed others?

Even Parikshit who placed a dead snake on the body of a meditating sage had to face the wrath of the sage's son. This shows that even enlightened swamis have no control over their anger issues. Forgive me if i said something wrong, but it seems the flames of anger cannot be easily subdued.

I would like to know its causes and the methods to curb it (without meditating ofcourse).